# how to extract timestamps and values from a file in c?

Tags: c

I need parse through a file and do some processing into it. The file is a text file and the data is a variable length data of the form  {"2014-02-13T06:20:00": "3.0", "2014-02-13T13:50:00": "7.0"} .So the 2014-02-13T06:20:00 is timestamp and 3.0 is the value.Now i need to sort the timestamp based on value.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is the data stored in json format or just bulk data?

Comment: why do you have the tag for C# if the question concern C ? Seems like JSON / Python dictionary

Comment: @Cotur bulk data

Comment: 1) C or C#?  2) Your question sounds like a "do-it-for-me" task.. Post your attempt, instead, and people will be glad to help you.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni i am just new at c programming and i dont now much

Answer (score 0):

Your source data looks like json and looks to be a simple key pair of a date time and a decimal value.

If you add the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to your project, you could load your data and sort it at the same time using the following code

```
            string json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
            SortedList<DateTime, decimal> data =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SortedList<DateTime, decimal>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you solution and explain step by step.
I assume that your programming language is C# and the all data is not stored json format.

First, we need to search values from the txt by regex.
So we need exact pattern that gives us the values correctly.
In the regular expression, there are groups so we can get the values that in group, I don't write all Regex fundamentals. see [Regex wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

so you can check it: https://www.debuggex.com/r/t6EiH6oQ84dqkFfL
for this regex, the group 1 is our datetime and group 7 is our value for any match.

We can iterate all Regex Matches to convert our data object, then we can use the LinQ power to order etc.

here is the full example for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyData
        {
            public DateTime ObjDateTime { get; set; }
            public float Value { get; set; }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern =
                "\"(\\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T(00|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(0[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):(0[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))\": \"(\\d\\.\\d)\"";

            string bulkData = "{\"2014-02-13T06:20:00\": \"3.0\", \"2014-02-13T13:50:00\": \"7.0\"}";

            Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            List<MyData> lst = new List<MyData>();

            foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(bulkData))
            {
                lst.Add(
                    new MyData()
                    {
                        ObjDateTime = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups.Values.Single(x => x.Name == "1").Value),
                        Value = float.Parse(match.Groups.Values.Single(x => x.Name == "7").Value)
                    });
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered by Value Asc");
            // order by value
            foreach (var myData in lst.OrderBy(x => x.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}, Value: {1}", myData.ObjDateTime, myData.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered by Value Desc");
            // order by desc value
            foreach (var myData in lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}, Value: {1}", myData.ObjDateTime, myData.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```